# How to solve Joomla 1.5 Error "Illegal variable _files or _env or _get or _post or _cookie or _server or _session or globals passed to script."

Tags: joomla, joomla1.5

I am currently hosting a Joomla 1.5 website when the content manager tried to change the content on the site (copy, pasted text from MS Word).

The website started generating this error

```
Illegal variable _files or _env or _get or _post or _cookie or _server or _session or globals passed to script.
```

I have never seen this error before and it restricts entry into the backend of the site also.

What could be the problem?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Look for "73647" text in your Joomla code. In some of my installations this code was injected in the original Joomla files.

Try to increase your website security.

Answer (score 0):

**The only solution that worked** is to comment out the following line in the `request.php` file.

Find the file here:

> `/{your_joomla_folder}/libraries/joomla/environment/request.php`

And uncomment as follows:

```
// $failed |= is_numeric( $key );
```